# Java DICOM metadata table

Tags: java, metadata, dicom

These are essentially the steps I need to follow. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

a. reading file dicom

b. reading medata of dicom

c. if VM >1 then create table of values else a value.

Comment: I'm not familiar with what sort of toolkit I need to be using or how to implement it.

Comment: Please take a look at the open-source [PixelMed](http://www.pixelmed.com/dicomtoolkit.html) toolkit, it should satisfy your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I found dcm4che (https://github.com/dcm4che/dcm4che) to be very complete in terms of DICOM standard support.
I am sure you would be able to access the information you are interested in with it.
You can either call the provided binaries (eg: dcm2xml: Convert DICOM file to XML presentation) and then process the output (XML, Json...) or call directly the API (and then the source of the above mentioned binary is a good starting point to know how to use the API).